# Mysql Update query is taking a lot of time

Tags: mysql, galera

I am having one mysql table which is having one column(numviews) on this table which is updated frequently(same update query run in a loop) . It is taking a lot of time more than 2secs and i am not able to find out how to improve this because it is affecting/slowing my application too which is having dependency on this table.   Here is mysql table.

**Note** : Its an innodb table and there is no other slow queries. This table is under mariadb galera cluster. I am having **300** max connections also. In any point of time the global connection doesn't go beyond 170/180.

```
CREATE TABLE `data_table` (
  `site` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `active` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `numclicks` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `numviews` INT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `country` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `viewcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comments` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `boost` FLOAT DEFAULT '0',
  `daily_limit` INT(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`site`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and here is the mysql update query which run on a loop(Its around 50 times the below query runs on this table).

```
UPDATE data_table  set numviews = numviews + 1 where site='xyz';

Query OK, 1 row affected (2.57 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0


SELECT site,active,numclicks,numviews,country,viewcount FROM data_table WHERE site='xyz'\G
*************************** 1. ROW ***************************
                    site: xyz
                  active: 1
               numclicks: 130406
                numviews: 48962
                 country: |xx yy |
               viewcount: 134022
```

**EDIT**: I can see some deadlock also.

```
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 2 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3020 page no 10 n bits 120 index `PRIMARY` of table `data_table`trx table locks 1 total table locks 47  trx id 71211631903 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 2 wait time before grant 0
------------------
---TRANSACTION 71211631885, ACTIVE 2 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1083597, OS thread handle 0x7f782a335700, query id 184464304 machine1 XX.XX.XX.XX user updating
UPDATE data_table set numviews = numviews + 1 where site='xyz'
Trx #rec lock waits 12 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 12 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 2 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3020 page no 10 n bits 120 index `PRIMARY` of table `data_table` trx table locks 1 total table locks 47  trx id 71211631885 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 2 wait time before grant 0
------------------
---TRANSACTION 71211631883, ACTIVE 2 sec
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1082885, OS thread handle 0x7f713e848700, query id 184464302 xxx XX.XX.XX.XX user query end
UPDATE data_table set numviews = numviews + 1 where site='xyz'
Trx #rec lock waits 225 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 366 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
```

Can anyone help me how to improve this update query ?

Comment: no.of rows you have in table?

Comment: @Rahul Less than 1000

Comment: @Strawberry Yes it is a loop i mean i am just incrementing the numviews by 1 , it is a process. I am having 300 max connections also. In any point of time the global connection doesn't go beyond 170/180.

Comment: I suspect they are the same @Strawberry

Comment: sorry my bad, updated the question

Comment: @Strawberry where clause is required because the site is unique.

Comment: @Strawberry Here is the scenario : Loop checks some condition if it satisfies then it updates the numviews. The loop is basically on  2M records.

Comment: how many nodes are in the cluster ? Does you update verytime over the same node ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen 2 nodes + 1(Garbd) . Its a cluster and it updates on the other nodes. So we update only one node always.

Comment: So each time it's called, the 'loop'  actually only runs once.

Comment: So I'm still confused about that '50 times' bit

Comment: i see 2 bad things. first use a int or bigint  with autoincrement as primary key and put a unique key on site. the primary key is use for nearly anything in galera also for update the other nodes. also you can use a new field siteMd5 varchar(32) where you store the md5 of site. then its much quicker to find the correct row. and the second split it in 2 tables. one with the new id and numviews and in the other id and the nearly static fields. so you reduce the read request in the system.

Comment: @Strawberry Because this loop create the 50 threads around and runs this update query.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that statement

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need that, what you are trying to do is update the column OR increment the `num_views` column. What I mean is, say you are looping for 1000 times and performing the `UPDATE`; Instead perform a single `update` with the value 1000 saying `set numviews = 1000 + 1` (OR) in other words if you have the total number of views value before hand then can perform a single `UPDATE` operation. If so then below code would do the same

```
UPDATE data_table set numviews = total_views + 1 where site='xyz';
```

Comment: Dont you think its same as UPDATE data_table  set numviews = numviews + 1 where site='xyz';

Comment: run the loop then update the number one time, good call Rahul!

Comment: @Sthita, NO, cause say you are looping for 1000 times and performing the UPDATE. Instead perform a single update with the value 1000 saying `set numviews = 1000 + 1`

Comment: Your query is a different update, than the update the questioner proposed. Meaning it does not do the same. The original update results in different numbers per row. Your update will set the whole column `numviews` to one value, which is likely not the desired result.

Comment: this makes no sense. More coffee required.

Comment: @GhostGambler, I don't think so, see OP's post ... update results in single row. which means the same row getting updated multiple times resulting in final value. that's why I made that guess.

Comment: But what has a column `numviews`, whose semantic is (from the name) to count the number of viewers of a specific row, to do with the total number of rows of the table?

Comment: @GhostGambler, Ahh ... total no.of rows is just an example. See my comment to OP. What I mean is perform a single update with the actual value than having multiple updates.

Comment: But how to combine `update test set value=5 where test="banana"` and `update test set value=3 where test="apple"` into one query?

Comment: @GhostGambler, you don't. you replace the where condition variable and set value in application code and call the same update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Rapidly changing counters (clicks, views) should be in a separate table.  That way, queries (reads and writes) that don't need those columns won't interfere with them.

Remove that `UPDATE` from any transaction -- do it as its own transaction.

How far apart are your Galera nodes?  If they are cross-country at, say, 100ms, then you can do only 10 such updates per second.  If that is your case read my [high speed ingestion blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table); then we can discuss how to use MyISAM on Galera to allow a much higher throughput of your `UPDATEs`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the site column has an index, or if you can determine site by ID instead of name would improve it much more. Create and set ID as primary key. Also, if there is only one site, you might improve it a bit with LIMIT 1. Else I'm not sure. Maybe you can improve it with PDO to prepare the same request with different values if you run it in a loop.

Comment: Yes as you can see site is a primary key. So it is by default has an index.

Comment: you are right, I saw it now in the end of the create table, thanks :)